# Linux command reset(1) is slow

Tags: linux

The console command `reset(1)` is, I think too slow. On my machine, it takes 1 sec wall time to execute.

Why is this? Can it be made fast? Alternatively, is there another command that can erase my terminal buffer?

Comment: You closed my question as off topic although it's a real usage problem for me. And even if asking why reset is slow might be a little funny, asking how I can erase my terminal buffer is certainly not.

Answer (score 9):

I ran `strace reset`, and saw this near the end:

```
nanosleep({1, 0}, 0x7fffe32053e0)       = 0
```

So it's deliberately waiting a second after sending all the terminal reset codes, probably because some terminals need time to process everything.

You shouldn't need to use `reset` very often (only when a full-screen program has terminated abnormally, so it doesn't reset the terminal itself), why is this a big deal?

I'm not sure what you mean by "erase my terminal buffer". That's not what `reset` is for.

Comment: Maybe that's not what `reset` is for, but I don't know what other command might have the same effect. Thanks however, this kind of explains why it is slow.

Comment: It is a big deal because I use `reset` very often when programming in some window terminal emulator, e.g. gnome-terminal. I often need to just clear my screen, but also erase the terminal buffer all the way up.

Comment: This explains why on some distributions in some rare cases it leaves garbage in the terminal. It clears the screen, then some terminal codes appear, and then I get the prompt.

Answer (score 5):

reset calls tput(1) with the clear, rmacs, rmm, rmul, rs1, rs2, and rs3 arguments. This causes tput to send appropriate reset strings to the terminal based on information in /etc/termcap (for the GNU or BSD tput) or in the terminfo database (for the ncurses tput). This sequence seems to be sufficient to reset the Linux VC's when they start printing "funny-looking" characters. For good measure, stty(1) is called with the sane argument in an attempt to get cooked mode back.

See also clear(1), stty(1), tput(1)

Comment: It seems that `tput reset` does the job for me, with no delay.

Comment: From tput(1): ``If tput is invoked by a link named reset, this has the same effect as tput reset.``, creating a symlink from ``tput`` to ``reset`` in my home bin folder did the trick. Thanks.

Comment: This does not answer the question of why `reset` is slow. Running those individual `tput` commands in sequence is fast. As another answer shows, the reason that `reset` is slow is that it deliberately sleeps.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to clear your terminal buffer, you could look at the [clear(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/clear) command.

An excerpt from the [clear(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/clear) manual page:

```
NAME
   clear - clear the terminal screen

SYNOPSIS
   clear

DESCRIPTION
   clear clears your screen if this is possible.  It looks in
   the environment for the terminal type and then in the 
   terminfo database to figure out how to clear the screen.
   ...
```

Comment: clear(1) clears the visible rectangle of characters in the terminal, not the entire terminal buffer. So clear(1) is not always sufficient